# How to show existing data in a select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show in a select box the existing email addresses of the users, who's department is "PA".
e.g. From below 3 email addresses, I want to show only "test1@person.com" and "test3@person.com".
(User.id: 1, email: "test1@person.com, department: "PA"), (User.id: 2, email: "tet2@person.com, department: "PB"), (User.id: 3, email: "test3@person.com, department: "PA")

Roles_controller

```
def create
    @mails = User.where(department: "PA")
...
```

roles.new.html.erb

```
<%= f.select :paman, @mails.map{|o| [o.email]} %>
```

But showing "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass".
It seems it's not identified as array...

I also changed controller

```
@mails = User.where(department: "PA").pluck(:email)
```

and view also

```
<%= f.select :paman, options_for_select(@mails { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] }), {prompt: "Select Role"}, class: "form-control" %>
```

But same error message was shown.

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you have the `@mails` variable being created inside the correct method?  You have it inside the `create` method, but it sounds like it should be inside the `new` method.  Your `create` method is likely only reached by a `post` method, where `new` displays a form and is reached via `get`, unless you have some kind of custom setup that is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sooooo stupid mistake.... The problem was solved!